# root directory in a web server

Tags: php, server, require

All my work on php and mysql was on local server.Now i want to move to a web host.I choose one of the free hosting sites like 1freehosting.I uploaded my php pages to the file manager of the hosting site's cpanel.

I used to access the `index.php`  under the folder name `'core'` page on my local server like the following :

```
localhost/practice/core/index.php
```

I wrote the  url with my domain name but got error .My domain name is ezphp.tk(it's also a free domain)

```
ezphp.tk/practice/core/index.php
```

But i got the following error

> Warning: require_once(../classes/Cookie.php): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   /home/u377815502/public_html/practice/core/init.php on line 42
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '../classes/Cookie.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in
>   /home/u377815502/public_html/practice/core/init.php on line 42

**My file structure in the host server is the following :**

root directory as i see is the following :

> file manager>practice>

inside practice i have the following folders:

> -classes-core-css-includes-function-editor

***my index.php is the following :***

```
<?php 

    require_once '../core/init.php';
    include('../includes/header.php');
    if(Session::exists('home')){
        echo '<p>'.Session::flash("home").'</p>';

    }


    if($user->isLoggedIn()){



?>
<p>Hellow <a href="../includes/profile.php?user=<?php echo escape($user->data()->username); ?>"><?php echo escape($user->data()->username); ?> </a>!</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href='../includes/logout.php'>logout</a></li>
    <li><a href='../includes/update.php'>update info</a></li>
    <li><a href='../includes/changepassword.php'>change your password</a></li>
    <li><a href="../includes/profile.php<?php echo '?user='.escape($user->data()->username);?>">profile</a></li>

</ul>
<?php
      if($user->hasPermission('moderator')){
          echo '<p>you ara a moderator</p>';
      }
    }else{

        echo '<p>you need to <a href="../includes/login.php">login</a> or <a href="../includes/register.php">register</a><p>';
    }
include('../includes/footer.php');
    ?>
```

Comment: The file init.php is calling a file named 'Cookie.php' in your classes folder, but it seems it doesn't finds it, maybe check your folder/file and find that file

Comment: cookei.php is under the " classes " folder which is in the same directory as practice/classes like practice/core

Answer (score 2):

Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` instead of using relative paths:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/init.php';
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/header.php');
```

Use this inside your other files as well, so that it's not trying to traverse odd paths.